# How to give Layout width, height to edit text programatically?

Tags: android

I have a problem I have created EditText run time in my code now I want to give  size(height and width) for that Edittext how can I do the same, like in xml file we give android:layout_heigtht and layout_width. How to do it programatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    addQuestion = new Button(myContext);
    addQuestion.setId(134);
    addQuestion.setTag("addQuestion");
    addQuestion.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add_button));
    addQuestion.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams addQuestion_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(24, 24);  
    addQuestion_Params.leftMargin=20;
    addQuestion.setOnClickListener(myScreenClickListener);        
    questionAndAddButtonContainer.addView(addQuestion, addQuestion_Params);
```

above given is an example of dynamically setting height and width of a button.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams addQuestion_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(24, 24);
```

here 24 is d width and height of the button.

Comment: I want one more thing can we give this size(24) as dip(density independent pixel),because in run time it's view not looking as required. Thanx

Comment: yes u can.just assign the value to 1 variable and use at variable in the place of 24.

Answer (score 1):

Use LayoutParams, to set the layout in the code.
I haven't tried this, but saw something similar to this in a related post.

Also this is provided as an answer by someone else, so it works, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Use setWidth and setHeight method. There's no layout property in code design. For more about TextView and EditText, look at the documentation: 
[TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)
[EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

And if you need to set the size in "dip", there's no dip when coding, you need the DisplayMetric, then calculate the size yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to set them with the setWidth(int width) and setHeight(int height). Something like this:

```
EditText edit = new EditText(this);
edit.setWidth(100);
edit.setHeight(50);
```